# Simple Ruby Rate Limiting

Tags: ruby, mutex, rate, rate-limiting

I am trying to build a very simple rate limit algorithm using an array.

Let's for example use the following rate limit as an example "5 requests every 5 minutes"

I have an array that stores a list of timestamps (where each element is a `Time.now`) and is added to the array when an API gets called (assuming it's under the rate limit)

I also used a Mutex here so different threads can both share the `timestamp` resource as well as ensuring there's no race condition happening.

However, I'd like this array to be self-cleaning of sorts. If there are 5 (or more) elements in the array AND one or more of it is outside of the 5 minute interval, it would automatically remove this entry.

And this is sort of where I am stuck on.

I have the following code:
    def initialize(max, interval)
      @max, @interval = max, interval
      @m = Mutex.new
      @timestamp = []
    end

```
def validate_rate
  @m.synchronize do
    if @timestamp.count > @max && self.is_first_ts_expired
      @timestamp.shift
      if self.rate_count < @max
        @timestamp << Time.now
        return false
      else
        return true
      end
    end
  end
end

def is_first_ts_expired
  return false if @@timestamp[@name].first.nil? # no logged entries = no expired timestamps
  return @@timestamp[@name].first <= Time.now - @interval
end

# Gets the number of requests that are under the allowed interval
def rate_count
  count = 0
  @timestamp.each { |x|
    if x >= Time.now - @interval
      count += 1
    end
  }
  count
end
```

The following is how you will call this simple class. `rl.validate_rate` will return `true` if it's under the rate limit, but false if it's above. And ideally it will self-clean the `timestamp` array when it's greater than the `max` variable.

```
rl = RateLimit.new(5, 5.minutes)
raise RateLimitException unless rl.validate_rate do
    # stuff
end
```

I am curious if where I put the "clean up" `is_first_ts_expired` code is called at the right place?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a totally valid approach.

Two quick notes:

1) It seems like you're only allowing insertion into the array when there are less than the max number of elements:

```
if rate_count < @max
  @timestamp << Time.now
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

However, you're also only clearing out expired elements when there are greater than the number of allowed elements in the array:

```
if @timestamp.count > max && is_first_ts_expired
  @timestamp.shift
```

I think in order to get this working, you want to remove that first condition when you are checking if you should clear elements from the array. It will look something like this:

```
if is_first_ts_expired
  @timestamp.shift
```

2) You will only ever clean one item out of your array here:

```
if is_first_ts_expired
  @timestamp.shift
```

To make this solution more robust, you may want to replace the `if` with a `while` so you can clean out multiple expired items. For example:

```
while is_first_ts_expired do
  @timestamp.shift
end
```

---

Updated based on comment below:

Since you'll potentially be going through all of the timestamps if the timestamps are all expired, you'll want to slightly modify the `is_first_ts_expired` to handle an empty `timestamp` array. Something like this:

```
def is_first_ts_expired
  current_ts = @timestamp.first
  current_ts && current_ts <= Time.now - @interval
end
```

Comment: It seems with the inclusion of `while self.is_first_ts_expired do`.. if `@timestamp.first` is empty, then it will throw an `undefined method <=' for nil:NilClass` error since it's trying to compare `nil` to `Time.now - @interval`

Comment: right, you'd probably need to change that method so that it returns false if `@timestamp.first` is `nil`. That makes sense though, as if there isn't a timestamp, then there is no first ts to be expired. I've edited my example code above to reflect that case.

Comment: Thanks! Why do you do a `current_ts && current_ts` here?

Comment: Please check my updated question - I updated my way of checking for `first.nil`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage i do `current_ts && current_ts <= Time.now...` because `current_ts &&` will return false if `current_ts` is `nil`. This will short circuit, so we don't ever evaluate the next section of code.